# Java for loop thread lock

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop, locking

I want the program loop 17 times through the models, but if I loop anything further than 5 the program freezes, I tried looking the problem up, it is because the edt cannot perform heavy tasks, but I've tried to create new threads inside the code to solve it but I don't seem to figure it out correctly.

P.S : program works so it's not a problem of the actual program it is the loop (that loops 17 times).

```
public synchronized void start(int max) {
    try {

        // max = total number of questions
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {

            //new cmd command
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");

            // new thread
            new Thread(() -> {
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        System.out.println(line);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }).start();

            //used to change text in files and the remaining cmd commands and move the result
            try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream())) {

                //to clear previous index folder and delete results folder
                deleteFile();

                //to rewrite the "collection.spec" folder with the address of the Answers file
                answerFile(i);

                //to rewrite the "trec.topics.list"" folder with the address of the Questions file
                questionFile(i);


                /* PROBLEM STARTS HERE! */
                for(int c = 1; c <= 17; c++) {

                    // after rename do the remaining cmd commands
                    out.println("C:/TERRIERS/terrier/bin/trec_terrier.bat -i");
                    out.println("C:/TERRIERS/terrier/bin/trec_terrier.bat -r");

                    //change model
                    modelSelect();
                }

                /* PROBLEM ENDS HERE!*/
                // .....
            }

            p.waitFor();

            //move the ".res" folder to the Results folder in projects directory 
            takeFile(i);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
    }

    catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
```

and this is **modelSelect** function

```
    int counter = 1;
    public void modelSelect() {

    //location of file
    String s = "C:\\TERRIERS\\terrier\\etc\\trec.models";

    try {

        FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(s);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        //depends on count value change the model inside "trec.models" and increase counter by 1

        switch (counter) {

        case 1 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.BM25"); counter++; break;
        case 2 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.DFR_BM25"); counter++; break;
        case 3 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.TF_IDF"); counter++; break;
        case 4 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.BB2"); counter++; break;
        case 5 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.IFB2"); counter++; break;
        case 6 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.In_expB2"); counter++; break;
        case 7 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.In_expC2"); counter++; break;
        case 8 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.InL2"); counter++; break;
        case 9 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.PL2"); counter++; break;
        case 10 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.DFR"); counter++; break;
        case 11 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.DFRWeightingModel"); counter++; break;
        case 12 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.DLH"); counter++; break;
        case 13 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.DLH13"); counter++; break;
        case 14 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.Hiemstra_LM"); counter++; break;
        case 15 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.Idf"); counter++; break;
        case 16 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.LemurTF_IDF"); counter++; break;
        case 17 : w.write("uk.ac.gla.terrier.matching.models.WeightingModel"); counter=1; break;//reset counter to 1
        }

        w.close(); 
    }
    catch (IOException e) { 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a thread? Why not run the process in-line? And why are you using a process at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is missing synchronisation.

You start two batch files (`out.println("C:/TERRIERS/terrier/bin/trec_terrier.bat -i"); out.println("C:/TERRIERS/terrier/bin/trec_terrier.bat -r");`) and without waiting for completion of these commands you call `modelSelect()` and start the next two batch files.

The java side of this whole process is blazingly fast - much faster than your batch files can be.

The best solution would be to wait for the batch files to complete. If this can't be done then at least change your code to

```
    out.println("C:/TERRIERS/terrier/bin/trec_terrier.bat -i");
    out.println("C:/TERRIERS/terrier/bin/trec_terrier.bat -r");

    Thread.sleep(100);

    //change model
    modelSelect();
```